# Getting a sublist that has 4 element

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Here is the code. The length of the sublist should be 3 (RGB). But I got 4.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

with Image.open("hash security.png") as img:
    width, height = img.size
    arr=list(img.getdata())
    print(arr)
```

Here is a snippet output.

```
[(255, 255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255, 255)]
```

Comment: maybe it is RGBa (where one of the values indicates transparency)

Comment: Print `img.mode` and see what pixel format you've got.

Comment: @martineau RGBA

Comment: That means that the image has an "alpha" layer indicating the transparency of each pixel. You can remove it with `img = img.convert("RGB")`.

Answer (score 1):

The fourth column for PNG is called alpha, it is used to indicate transparency. You can slice the list if you don't need it:

```
with Image.open("hash security.png") as img:
    width, height = img.size
    arr=list(img.getdata())[:-1]
    print(arr)
```

Comment: `arr=list(img.getdata())[:-1]` is just slicing the final part the whole list, but not alpha.

Comment: Wasif: I think `arr = [p[:-1] for p in img.getdata()]` would work better. Also, printing its entire contents like that is likely going to produce an excessive and undesirable about of output.